# codeigniter email weirdness

Tags: php, email, codeigniter

I am trying to send email via codeigniter framework via 2 different ways and on one of them my email goes to junk folder but its really weird...

so my first try was to create a Controller and put inside the index function the following code:

```
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->from('no-reply@domain.example.com', 'Your Name');
    $this->email->to('email@example.com');
    $this->email->subject('Email Test');
    $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');
    $this->email->send();
    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

this way the email arrives fine and not as spam...

when i create a model so i can use it later on for other features to send emails i replace the above code with the following one:

```
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->load->model("email_model");
    $this->email_model->sendEmail(null, 'email@gmail.com', 'title', 'message');
```

and email_model Model contains the following code :

```
<?php
class email_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }

   public function sendEmail($from = null, $to = null, $subject = null, $message = null){
        $this->email->from('no-reply@domain.com', 'from user');
        $this->email->to($to);
        $this->email->subject($subject);
        $this->email->message($message);
        $this->email->send();
   }
}
```

why does that happen?

Comment: Compare the message headers on both messages. There must be something different between the two. The only thing I see here that's different is the message and the subject on the 'spam' email are much shorter. Is your email provider filtering out the single word message?

Comment: why i cant see any difference in the headers? there probably should be something different right? i dont know if email provider has filtered out any words... my email provider is godaddy btw...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems content was the reason on the 2nd try... adding more text solved the issue...

Answer (score 1):

check your spf records and RDNS records

### SPF

here is an article @ mediatemple kb: http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/658/How+can+I+create+an+SPF+record+for+my+domain%3F#gs

### RDNS

here is an article on RDNS:
http://www.crucialp.com/resources/tutorials/web-hosting/how-reverse-dns-works-rdns.php

Comment: i have added my spf record but still getting email as spam... maybe i need to wait for sometime... ?