# codeigniter email sent to spam

Tags: php, email, codeigniter, spam

my model:

```
<?php
class email_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }

        public function sendEmail($from = null, $to = null, $subject = null, $message = null){

            $this->load->library('email');

            $config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
            $config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
            $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
            $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
            $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

            $this->email->initialize($config);

            $this->email->from('email@mydomain.com', 'Website name');

            $this->email->to($to);

            $this->email->subject($subject);

            $this->email->message($message);

            $this->email->send();

        }
}
```

my domain is hosted on GoDaddy also i have created an email there and redirect it to my gmail email...

why does my email is sent to spam folder and not on Inbox?

EDIT: my email content is basically an invitation welcome

```
Hello $email

$website has invited you to join the website

to join visit the following link

$link_goes_here

Thanks, the team
```

Comment: Depends on what you are sending and has little to do with the code you use to send it. Gmail's spam filter is very good, and if it considers your email spam I am curious what its contents are.

Comment: Consider having a look at [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555145/sending-email-with-gmail-smtp-with-codeigniter-email-library).

Comment: Agreed with the above 2 comments, you may also wish to look at your previous questions and select answers where appropriate

Comment: @jeshurun i have updated my question with the content of the email

Comment: It could be a number of things... The subject, content, sender or even the IP address you are sending from. a) Subject, content and sender: try putting the content of your email etc through tools such as http://www.americaint.com/spam-filter-messagetest/spam-checker.html b) go to http://www.mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx and put in the IP address of your server.

Comment: @gavin, first link is clear but how the hell am i on 2 blacklists when i sent non spam mails?

Comment: It all depends on the way your server is setup. If you have a dedicated server, it could depend on the ISP that your server uses, if your on a shared server, it's most likely because the range of IP's they own have been abused by other users and have been blacklisted.

Comment: i am on a VPS... do i have to structure my email content better to avoid the spam because its plain text with some colors?

Comment: Unfortunately, if the IP of your server is blacklisted, there is very little you can do, other than appeal to the companies who have blacklisted you and advise them you are not sending spam emails. I found that even if you are on a single, dedicated IP, the ISP it self could be blocked due to a vast number of spam emails being sent from IP's in it's range.

Comment: thing is that it works if i use gmail smtp but fails with the codeigniter method... i can even send 4 words with gmail and it wont be sent to spam folder

Comment: Unless you change the CodeIgniter email configuration to use an external SMTP such as GMail, any emails you send, will be sent via the VPS, thus via the blacklisted IP addresses, resulting in them ending up in spam.

Comment: i ended up using sendgrid... thanks for the help all!

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10288590/codeigniter-email-weirdness/10290530#10290530

Answer (score -1):

If you are using HTML to display your mail, you have to ensure that your mail is sent with valid html. 
You can validate your mail here: http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score -1):

if it, a contact us form..
maybe you can try to send an email through Amazon SES, so google / yahoo didn't think it as a spam